# Disable the mouseover effect on an XCeed WinForms DataGrid?

Tags: c#, winforms, mouseover, xceed, xceed-datagrid

I am using the Xceed WinForms DataGrid control but don't seem to be able to remove the mouseover row highlight effect. I have tried changing the DataGrid to readonly and changing the SelectionMode to None but it still insists on highlighting the row when I mouseover.

I can't find anything in the documentation that would suggest how to do this.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting `myGrid.DataRowTemplate.OverrideUIStyle = true;` and then setting something like :

```
// custom selection colors
myGrid.SelectionVisualStyle.BackColor = Color.Blue;
myGrid.SelectionVisualStyle.ForeColor = Color.Yellow;

// custom MouseOver colors
myGrid.DataRowTemplate.HotVisualStyle.BackColor = Color.Orange;
myGrid.DataRowTemplate.HotVisualStyle.ForeColor = Color.White;
```